# Problems with Django's dispatcher

Tags: django, dispatcher

I have some problems with the URL dispatching. There're my rules:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('proxy.views',
    (r'^$', 'proxyviews.index'),
    (r'^go/(?P<url>\S+)', 'proxyviews.go'),
    (r'^proxy/(\S+)$', 'proxyviews.proxy'),
)
```

If I give it the next URL: "http://myproxy.com/go/http://foo.bar" it will be "http://myproxy.com/go/http:/foo.bar" -- with one slash after "go/http:". I'm not sure what's wrong here. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: your question is not clear here, you mean if you don't give slash at end it redirect and put new slash at end in url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in your url you are giving raw string so "\" means "\" only. For this to work better use [url encode](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).

For eg instead of

> http://myproxy.com/go/http://foo.bar

you should give url as

> http://myproxy.com/go/http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.bar

Moreover you should also encode "%", so better it be

> http://myproxy.com/go/http%253A%252F%252Ffoo.bar

thanks

Comment: This is very strange. I got my code working fine on the another sserver. Doesn't this rule '^go/(?P<url>\S+)' shouldn't copy all string to 'url' variable? And why it's working on one server and it deosn't working on another one?

Comment: http://myproxy.com/go/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com -- `Not Found
The requested URL /go/http://www.google.com was not found on this server` -- any idea why?

Comment: your regular expression does not support %.

Comment: Nope, I have added the next rule: '^go/(?P<url>([a-zA-Z0-9]|%2F)+)' but still got 404 error :-( If I delete %2F from the URL, it works ok

Comment: I think that Django uses os.environ['PATH_INFO'] which is decoded :-/